# Count the number of lines of a long title with a specific line width

Tags: line, count

I am working on an effect of automatically fit an arbitrary long title to multi-lines with a specific line width. The title has no explicit new line(s), and is only a regular string. Currently, I have the following code to count the number of lines:

```
\newcounter{numbertitlelines}
% Define a macro to calculate the number of title lines
% #1: The length of title line (set by paper)
% #2: The text of title (set by user)
\newlength{\titlelength}
\def\cuz@macro@numbertitlelines#1#2{
    \settowidth{\titlelength}{#2}
    \setcounter{numbertitlelines}{0}
    \loop{
        \stepcounter{numbertitlelines}
    }\ifdim\titlelength>\value{numbertitlelines}#1\repeat
}
```

Yet sometimes it does not work very well for English, because the texts on different lines have different lengths in most cases (while Chinese titles works well since the same text width):

[image]

In the figure above, the numbers of underlines of (Chinese and English) titles are both determined by the count `numbertitlelines`.

Is there a method to check the text width in each line, or maybe some different thought to solve this problem?

BTW: it should work with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.   What do you need this line count for?

Comment: @AndrewSwann To draw the correct underlines adaptive to both titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you wanted to do this to add underlining, let me point to two ways to do this without counting the lines yourself.  Firstly, you can use one of the "unexpected purposes" of the `lineno` package.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \centering\internallinenumbers
  \renewcommand{\makeLineNumber}{\rule[-2pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hss}%
  A VERY COMMON \LaTeX\ THESIS TEMPLATE OF COMMUNICATION UNIVERSITY OF
  ZHEJIANG
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Secondly, if you do not want the lines to span the width of the box, but just the given text, then you can instead use the `ulem` package:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \centering
  \uline{A VERY COMMON \LaTeX\ THESIS TEMPLATE OF COMMUNICATION UNIVERSITY OF
  ZHEJIANG}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's just the result I wanted, although I don't quite understand the mechanism of the `lineno` package here.

Comment: `lineno` package essentially gives a way to do something for each line in a text block.  Its standard use is to update a counter and print its value in the margin, thus numbering the lines.  In this case, we do no counting, just print a horizontal line.

Comment: I see, that's really a tricky code. Thanks again for your kind help!

Answer (score 4):

For counting number of lines internal TeX counter `\prevgraf` is available that contains number of lines for currently formed or just closed paragraph (see *The TeXbook*, chapter 14). So this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{numbertitlelines}
\newlength{\titlelength}
\newbox\titlebox % auxiliary box
\newcount\titlelines % auxiliary counter
\newcommand{\titleformat}{\bfseries\centering} % format of title output
\newcommand*{\titlelinescount}[2]{%
    \setbox\titlebox=\vbox{\hsize=#1 \titleformat
        #2\par
        \global\titlelines=\the\prevgraf
    }
    \setcounter{numbertitlelines}{\the\titlelines}
}
\begin{document}

% -- Test --
\newcommand{\Title}{ A VARY COMMON \LaTeX\ THESIS TEMPLATE OF COMMUNICATION UNIVERSITY OF ZHEJIANG}
\newlength{\parlength}
\setlength{\parlength}{0.35\textwidth}

\titlelinescount{\parlength}{\Title}

The title \parbox{\parlength}{\titleformat\Title} contains \thenumbertitlelines\ lines


\end{document}
```

makes this result:

[image]

Macro `\titleformat` contains settings for title output providing a correspondence with title format in counting command. I set `\bfseries\centering` for example.

Auxiliary TeX counter `\titlelines` serves to globally save `\prevgraf` value in `\vbox`. Of course, you can use this counter directly if you want, without  `numbertitlelines` counter.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, it is clear and I managed to fix the bug :).